# Google contacts service Contact query OrderBy parameter values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, google-contacts-api

I am using google contacts service with .net mvc and I want to load 100 most contacted persons with ContactQuery.NumberToRetrieve and ContactQuery.OrderBy.
what should I set to OrderBy to make it work?
thanks a lot

Comment: I really nead it, Isn't there anyone to help?:-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query.OrderBy = "lastmodified";
query.SortOrder = "descending";
query.NumberToRetrieve = 1000 //Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NumberToRetrieve"]);
```

Comment: You can also have this values in web.config file.

Comment: what does sortOrder=descending mean?  What field in the contact is is descending sorted by?  It doesn't specify?